# Difference Between Web App and Web App for Containers

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, containers

We store container images in an Azure Container Registry. I want to create a web app for the container. In Azure marketplace, Web App and Web App for Containers are different resource types. Both seem to allow me to deploy my image from the container registry.

What's the difference between these two resources? Why might I choose one over the other?

Comment: Comparing Container Apps with other Azure container options:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/compare-options

Comment: @narthring The question is comparing Azure App Service Web Apps vs Azure App Service Web Apps for Containers, not Azure Container Apps

Answer (score 1):

They are essentially the same thing. When you select Web Apps for Containers, the **Publish** setting is set to **container** by default and when you select Web Apps, it's set to **code** but you can toggle from one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to CSharpRocks's response.

Sharing info for clarity on different deployment flavors in Azure App service:

**1.Code + Windows** – You select the Application stack and deploy your code.

2.Code + Linux (WebApp Linux) - App Service on Linux provides pre-defined application stacks on Linux with support for languages such as .NET, PHP, Node.js and others. These are blessed images, predefined by platform. Here you just deploy your code.

3.Docker Container + Linux **(WebApp for Container)** – custom image (code already part of the image, and not deployed separately) - container image become containers at runtime.

4.Docker Container + Windows (WebApp for Windows Container) – custom image – container image become containers at runtime.

1 or 2 and 3 are the options you are wanting to compare.